# Uncaught TypeError: $(...). is not a function when I import a library with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to import a library inside my bundle and I try in every way, but everytime I get an error.

The library is [Justified-Gallery](https://github.com/miromannino/Justified-Gallery) but sometimes this happen also with other library and I have to understand where is the issue.

I'm using webpacker with Rails.

This is my entry point, and `lightGallery`, another library I'm using, is working.

```
import 'lightgallery/scss/lightgallery-bundle'

// init vendor
import lightGallery from 'lightgallery'
import lgThumbnail from 'lightgallery/plugins/thumbnail'
import lgZoom from 'lightgallery/plugins/zoom'

window.lgZoom = lgZoom
window.lgThumbnail = lgThumbnail
window.lightGallery = lightGallery
require('justifiedGallery')


// init global user javascript
import './js/init.js';
```

Init.js is my main script

```
import NavbarSingleTon, { Navbar } from './navbar';
import GallerySingleTon, { Gallery } from './gallery';

(function init() {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    Navbar.init();
    Gallery.init();
  });
}());
```

And finally this is my gallery.js

```
export class Gallery {
  constructor($el) {
    $el.justifiedGallery({
      captions: false,
      lastRow: "hide",
      rowHeight: 180,
      margins: 5
    })
    .on("jg.complete", function () {
      window.lightGallery(
        document.getElementById("dmove_gallery"),
        {
          autoplayFirstVideo: false,
          pager: false,
          galleryId: "dmove",
          plugins: [lgZoom, lgThumbnail],
          mobileSettings: {
            controls: false,
            showCloseIcon: false,
            download: false,
            rotate: false
          }
        }
      );
    });
  }

  static init() {
    $(".gallery-container").each((i, el) => new Gallery($(el)));
  }
}
```

The error I have in console is

```
gallery.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).justifiedGallery is not a function
```

I try to understand why, and `require('justifiedGallery'`) require [this script](https://github.com/miromannino/Justified-Gallery/blob/master/src/js/jquery.justifiedGallery.js)

I try with

```
import justifiedGallery from 'justifiedGallery'
window.justifiedGallery = justifiedGallery
```

But nothing...
I cannot solve this issue